# Garuda Linux : annoying network problem

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, pacman, garuda-linux

I've installed Garuda Linux on my machine and upgraded the system. However, after I reboot, I face a wifi connection problem : the network manager cannot detect my wifi router but only detects my phone if I set it as a mobile hotspot.
I've been searching a lot for a fix to this issue and I even reinstalled Garuda so many times but after I reboot I come to face that annoying problem again.

I've tried many solutions provided for such a problem in various websites and forums and none of them did work :

1. restarting the network manager with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`
2. disabling wifi powersave
3. adding 2 lines as following to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

4. adding 2 lines as following to `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/nm.conf` :

```
[device]
wifi.backend=iwd
```

and I ran these commands :

```
sudo pacman -S iwd
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
sudo systemctl mask wpa_supplicant
sudo systemctl enable --now iwd.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start iwd.service
```

5. I also restarted my wifi router in vain

So what shall I do now ?

### NOTE :

Sometimes when trying some of the mentionned fixes, the network manager detects my wifi router but it cannot connect to it and shows : Authorization supplicant failed

Comment: If the authorization failed, you either typed the wrong password, or you ran into a "known-bug", to which the work-around seems to be to install `connman-git`.

Comment: @LjmDullaart the password is correct. But could you clarify the 2nd point ?

Comment: As I understand, there is a bug in certain `connman` versions that make authentication a problem. Installing the `connman-git` seems to be a workaround. As I don't run Garuda myself, I jus passed the info in the comments.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I'm not using connman but instead the Garuda network manager.